# Define a textconv driver outside of git config?

Tags: xcode, git, gitlab

I have a .strings file that git interprets as binary by default, but I want everyone on my team to see the diff on GitLab when I create a pull request.

[As per documentation](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv), I'm able to see the diff locally when I add `*.strings diff=Localizable` to .gitattributes and this textconv driver to .git/config:

```
[diff "Localizable"]
    textconv = "iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8"
    binary = false
```

The problem is, we don't commit the .git/config file, so everyone would have to add this to their config file and we still wouldn't be able to see the diff while reviewing code on GitLab. Is there a way to define textconv in a file that's safe to commit? I tried adding it to .gitattributes instead but it did nothing.

In case it matters, this is an Xcode project.

Comment: I've added the [tag:gitlab] tag in case there are special magic things you can enable on GitLab to add textconv filters for merge request reviews. (I don't know if there are, but GitLab do have the concept of CI/CD with virtual machines that let admins run admin commands *on* the virtual machines, so there's room to fit such things in to their security models.)

Comment: The solution to my problem is unrelated to this question, so I'll leave it as a comment. I changed the file encoding to UTF-8, [as Apple recommends for .strings files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html). I had tried this initially but it only worked once I deleted the file and readded it, setting the encoding from the beginning. Also, GitLab doesn't support UTF-16 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

No.

This is unfortunate, but it's also necessary for security, because if you could define a `textconv` filter in a file that *did* get committed, a bad actor could define a fake filter that (while maybe doing some textconv-ing) acted as a Trojan horse, for instance.

What you *can* do is provide a script that sets this up for users, and tell them *inspect the script if you like, and then if you trust it, run it to set things up*.  (Make the script as simple as you can so that people can inspect it first, though you might want to have it look to see if it's already been run and not do anything in that case.)

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! I'll see if I can find some useful configuration on GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

As torek mentioned, specifying textconv is not practical for security reasons. The best that you might be able to do is add a `.gitattributes` file in the root of your repository that declares this as text (like `*.strings text=true`) rather than binary. This should at least help you see the diffs in GitLab.

You need to commit your `.gitattributes` file to the *default* branch (e.g. `master` or `main`) of the project before it will have any effect. Changes to `.gitattributes` files in any other branches will have no effect on how diffs are viewed in the GitLab UI.

You *must* also commit the `.gitattributes` file with UTF-8 encodings for it to work, per the [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/git_attributes.html)